# Show an "alert popup" and redirect to a website if return is true

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show an "alert popup" on load and ask a question in it.

If result is true (meaning user clicked OK) it will open a link in a new window / tab or whatever the browser has set to do.

The code I am using right now is;

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        function getConfirmation(){
           var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
           if( retVal == true ){
              window.open("http://www.w3schools.com", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
           }
           else{
              Document.write ("User does not want to continue!");
              return false;
           }
        }
     //-->
getConfirmation();
  </script>
```

However this gets blocked by chrome because it's seen as a "popup" while it's definitely right after a user click.

What is the correct way of doing this / what am I doing wrong?

PS, I don't want to use jquery for this but purely JS, so no modalbox alternatives are possible.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery to create a modal dialogue box, you can do it with pure JS and CSS. What do you think jQuery uses to do it?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the clarification, let me put it like this: It needs to be in the same nature of the alert box.

Comment: Needs to be, or you would like it to be because you don't feel like writing the code for an HTML dialogue?

Comment: @Snowlav what does "same nature as alert" mean? How is a modal different?

Comment: It needs to keep unwanted traffic out of the redirection, like crawlers etc, an alert box works best for this according to my concept.

Comment: by the way, you don't have to write `if( retVal == true)`, just `if( retVal )`, or even more simply: `if( confirm('Do you want to continue?') )`